# setpriority() doesn't change the thread's priority

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

My threads have default scheduling policy SCHED_OTHER and it has the priority as 0, so they don't have priority level. Or in other words, you can't change the priority using (sched_param) param.sched_priority.

1. So, this means using system call pthread_setschedparam is ruled out.
2. pthread_setschedprio(std::thread::native_handle(), -1)  - this doesn't affect the thread's priority. I verified using getpriority (PRIO_PROCESS, tid). Can we use pthread_setschedprio() for default schedulers?

After carefully reading [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) page, I understood that I need to change the thread's dynamic priority by tweaking the nice value which can be achieved by either of these:

1. nice(19);

   - I tried this and it doesn't have any effect. I hope it is process wide nice value change.
   - I ruled this out too.
2. setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, id, 19)

- It returns -1 always and errno is ESRCH (No such process). Why this is not working?
- According to [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html), it can be used to change the priority of the thread.

3. syscall(SYS_sched_setattr, id, &attr, flags)

   struct sched_attr attr;
   unsigned int flags = 0;

   attr.size = sizeof(attr);
   attr.sched_nice = 6;
   attr.sched_policy = SCHED_OTHER;

   - This also didn't work, no luck.

**I want to lower the priority of these threads(this consumes more CPU) in a process without changing the policy. This ensures other threads which has the same priority as these to get CPU time**

Answer:

The priority of the threads is changed by passing the argument as gettid as below
setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, static_cast<pid_t>(syscall(SYS_gettid), 19);

Comment: As mentioned in the question, pthread_setschedparam() can't be used for SCHED_OTHER policy.

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary: context suggests that you're on Linux, so portions of this answer are Linux specific.

> My threads have default scheduling policy SCHED_OTHER and it has the priority as 0, so they don't have priority level. Or in other words, you can't change the priority using (sched_param) param.sched_priority.

That seems to mischaracterize the situation a bit.  Per [`sched`(`7`)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html),

> For threads scheduled under one of the normal scheduling policies (`SCHED_OTHER`, `SCHED_IDLE`, `SCHED_BATCH`), `sched_priority` is not used in scheduling decisions (it must be specified as 0).

You appear to be interpreting that or some alternative formulation of it to be a speaking about the behavior of certain system interfaces, such as `pthread_setschedprio()`.  Perhaps that comes from "it must be specified as 0", but the part to focus on is rather "not used in scheduling decisions".  Threads scheduled according to the `SCHED_OTHER` policy effectively do not have a priority property at all.  Their scheduling does not take any such property into account.

> 1. So, this means using system call pthread_setschedparam is ruled out.

Well, no, not exactly.  With `pthread_setschedparam()` you can set *both* the policy and the priority.  If you set the policy to one that considers thread priorities, then you can also meaningfully set the priority.  Not that I'm recommending that.

> 2. pthread_setschedprio(std::thread::native_handle(), -1) - this doesn't affect the thread's priority.

It shouldn't if the thread's scheduling policy is `SCHED_OTHER`.  Again, threads scheduled according to that policy do not actually have priority, and according to the docs, the (unused) value of their priority properties should be 0.

> I verified using getpriority (PRIO_PROCESS, tid).

You *should* verify by observing that `pthread_setschedprio()` fails with `EINVAL`.

> Can we use pthread_setschedprio() for default schedulers?

If by "default schedulers" you mean `SCHED_OTHER` then no.  See above.  If you include the realtime schedulers `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR` then yes, for threads scheduled via those schedulers.

> After carefully reading this page, I understood that I need to change the thread's dynamic priority by tweaking the nice value

Traditionally and per POSIX, individual threads do not have "nice" values.  These are properties of *processes*.  On systems where that is the case, you cannot use niceness to produce different scheduling behavior for different threads of the same process.

On Linux, however, individual threads *do* have their own niceness.  I don't particularly recommend relying on that, but if you

- do not require portability beyond Linux,
- must provide preferrential scheduling of some threads of one process over other threads of that process, and
- must use the `SCHED_OTHER` scheduling policy

then it's probably your best option.

> 2. setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, id, 19)
>
>    - It returns -1 always and errno is ESRCH (No such process). Why this is not working?

The system is telling you that `id` is not a valid process ID.  I speculate that it is a `pthread_t` obtained via `std::thread::native_handle()`, but note that although on Linux, `setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, ...)` can set per-thread niceness, the `pid_t` identifier it expects is not drawn from the same space as pthreads thread identifiers.  See [`gettid`(`2`)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html).

> 3. syscall(SYS_sched_setattr, id, &attr, flags)

If you're using the same `id` that elicits an ESRCH from `setpriority()` then I would not expect the `sched_settatr` syscall to like it any better just because you invoke that directly.

Comment: I have all threads' std::thread, so passed std::thread::get_id as id in setpriority(). How can I convert std::thread::get_id() to gettid() considering that this setpriority() should be called from outside of the threads?

Comment: I'm sorry, @Rose, but I'm not aware of any way to convert `pthread_t` values to corresponding `pid_t` values such as `gettid()` would return.  I can't say for sure that there isn't one, but we're already getting into the weeds with `gettid()`.  I suggest teaching your threads to de-prioritize themselves, or maybe to report out their own tid values to some place where you can access them from other threads.